# Table view pushes to top of screen

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Adding a tableView to a view below other items (images, fields, text, etc) and the table pushes the other items off the screen.

In the following example, I add a label to a view, then a table to a view.  The view is then added to the window.  The top of the table will push the label off the top of the screen.  If I swipe down, it is there though.

Has anyone else seen this?  Am I missing something?

```js
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
 layout : 'vertical',
});

var tableData = [{
 title : 'Apples'
}, {
 title : 'Bananas'
}, {
 title : 'Carrots'
}, {
 title : 'Potatoes'
}, {
 title : 'Apples'
}, {
 title : 'Bananas'
}, {
 title : 'Carrots'
}, {
 title : 'Potatoes'
}, {
 title : 'Apples'
}, {
 title : 'Bananas'
}, {
 title : 'Carrots'
}, {
 title : 'Potatoes'
}, {
 title : 'Apples'
}, {
 title : 'Bananas'
}, {
 title : 'Carrots'
}, {
 title : 'Potatoes'
}];

var view = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
 backgroundColor : 'transparent',
 top : 0,
 left : 0,
 width : 'auto',
 height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
 layout : 'vertical',
 id : 'mainView',
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
 color : 'white',
 text : 'I am label 1',
 font : {
  fontSize : 50,
 },
 top : 0,
});
view.add(label1);

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
 data : tableData,
 top : 0
});

view.add(table);
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct. Don't mix scrollviews (a tableview automatically scrolls). The thing you are seeing is: you add a label into a scrollview and then a table (height 100%) into the same scrollview. So you have label height + 100% and the label is moved outside the viewport.

Now when you scroll you will move the tableview at first and when it is scrolled all the way up the scrollview is scrolled and you will see your label again.

**What you can do:**

change the `createScrollView` to a normal `createView`

or

add the label as a TableViewRow (you can create custom layouts inside each row so it looks like a headline)

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: 'vertical',
});

var tableData = [{
    title: 'Apples'
}, {
    title: 'Bananas'
}, {
    title: 'Carrots'
}, {
    title: 'Potatoes'
}, {
    title: 'Apples'
}, {
    title: 'Bananas'
}, {
    title: 'Carrots'
}, {
    title: 'Potatoes'
}, {
    title: 'Apples'
}, {
    title: 'Bananas'
}, {
    title: 'Carrots'
}, {
    title: 'Potatoes'
}, {
    title: 'Apples'
}, {
    title: 'Bananas'
}, {
    title: 'Carrots'
}, {
    title: 'Potatoes'
}];

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 'auto',
    height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    layout: 'vertical',
    id: 'mainView',
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color: 'white',
    text: 'I am label 1',
    font: {
        fontSize: 50,
    },
    top: 0,
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE
});
view.add(label1);

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: tableData,
    top: 0
});

view.add(table);
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

second example

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = '#000';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: 'vertical',
});



var tableData = [];

function createHeadline(txt) {
    var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color: 'white',
        text: txt,
        font: {
            fontSize: 50,
        },
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE
    });
    var r1 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE
    });
    var v1 = Ti.UI.createView({
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    });
    v1.add(label1);
    r1.add(v1);
    tableData.push(r1);
}

function createRow(txt) {
    var r1 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE
    });
    var v1 = Ti.UI.createView({
        height: 40,
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    });
    var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color: 'white',
        text: txt,
        font: {
            fontSize: 18,
        },
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE
    });
    v1.add(label1);
    r1.add(v1);
    tableData.push(r1);
}

createHeadline("Label 1");
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createHeadline("Label 2");
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createRow("text")
createRow("text")

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: tableData,
    top: 0
});

win.add(table);
win.open();
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  I changed createScrollView to createView and it works!  For science, I will also test your other suggestion.

Cheers!